# iOS how to test a method that calls the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:someUrl]

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd

I want to create a test for the method bellow, I would like to check if the forgot password is right. I'm new on TDD and I would like to know if you guys think this is necessary and how could I implement the test.

```
- (IBAction)forgotPasswordButtonClicked:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kForgetPasswordURL]];
```

}

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the new class with the static method and to solve my problem I used a partial mock from the Specta framework:
`id mockApplication = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];`

I guess this is a better solution. (I didn't know partial mocks before)

Comment: With OCMock, I'm getting an 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' when trying to create this mock as you state above. I am trying to run this test in a static library. Do you think that is what's causing it?

Comment: Experiencing the same thing as AnthonyM since updating to OCMock 3 (it worked in 2).

Answer (score 8):

For OCMock 3, try the following:

```
id mockApplication = OCMClassMock([UIApplication class]);
OCMStub([mockApplication sharedApplication]).andReturn(mockApplication);

OCMVerify([mockApplication openURL:[OCMArg any]]);
```

[This](http://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/mocking-stubbing/#ocmock) article helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do that by creating a new class that handles the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:], I did this by adding an static method on this new class. I'm still not sure if this is a good approach, but solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can create XCTest to test following method.

However you have to create a test target for your project and create XCTestCase if one is not created by default, on your test target and create a method starting with the name testForgotPassWordButtonClicked.

To run the test target, create a schema for test target and run test on it.

Comment: I'm already doing TDD on this project, I'm using the Specta framework. But I don't know yet how to do this test specifically.Thanks

Comment: This answer is too high-level and is irrelevant to the specifics of the question.